# Apache2 not working after SSL certificate remove

Tags: apache, ubuntu, ssl, digital-ocean

im using vesta cp i remove the keys on the settings of the domain and the apache  is not working how can i make it work again

- Restarting web server apache2
  ...fail!
- The apache2 configtest failed.

Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 83 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/vesta.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /home/admin/conf/web/sapache2.conf:  without matching  section
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.

Error log

- [Sun Dec 04 06:43:37.530259 2016] [:notice] [pid 1881]
  mod_ruid2/0.9.8 enabled
- [Sun Dec 04 06:43:37.535379 2016] [ssl:warn] [pid 1881] AH02292:
  Init: Name-based SSL virtual hosts only work for clients with TLS
  server name indication support (RFC 4366)
- [Sun Dec 04 06:43:37.535844 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1881]
  AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) mod_fcgid/2.3.9 PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17
  OpenSSL/1.0.1f configured -- resuming normal operations
- [Sun Dec 04 06:43:37.535858 2016] [core:notice] [pid 1881] AH00094:
  Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
- [Mon Dec 05 18:42:53.735381 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1881]
  AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down

Answer (score 0):

Run as root this command:

> v-rebuild-user admin